# Checking for undefined every time when function parameter is missing

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am working on a js code snippet to make a function which can be called with object literal.

Problem area : If i do not need to track the product value then a check has been placed for undefined. But do i really need to make check for each & every value if its not there in the object literal.
Below is the code.

```
trackProduct = function (args) {

      if(args.label == undefined) {
        value.push([args.category, args.action, args.value]);
      } else if(args.value == undefined){
        value.push([args.category, args.action, args.label]);
      } else {
        value.push([args.category, args.action, args.label, args.value]);
      }
};
```

Calling this function via below object literal. I have not passed the value parameter. Do we need to check for Undefined for all three paramters?

```
trackProduct({
    category: elemcategory,
    action: elemaction,
    label: elemlabel
});
```

Any suggestions on how to improve on this code.

Comment: What you have done is fine and readable, it's fine if its working. Its better not to optimise a lot and tamper the readability unless optimisation is necessary. But obviously it's good to look for better styles...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
trackProduct = function (args) {
    var tempArray = [];

    args.category && tempArray.push(args.category);
    args.action && tempArray.push(args.action);
    args.label && tempArray.push(args.label);
    args.value && tempArray.push(args.value);

    value.push(tempArray); // [["elemcategory", "elemaction", "elemlabel"]]
};
```

Also as @jisi pointed out, if any of these can hold falsy values like 0,'' etc then this simple condition wont stand. in that case, `typeof(args.category) === 'undefined'` should be used.

Which even i dint recomment unless you are ok with the redability and is sure people who are going to read the code will understand this.

Above example illustrates handling undefined values.

---

Iterating objects can be done by [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
var tempArray = [];
for (var prop in args) tempArray.push(args[prop]);
value.push(tempArray);
```

Comment: This will give him pretty strange behavior when any of the values are 0 or an empty string ...

Comment: @jishi  thank you for pointing that out, I have added it along with the answer.